# Socket Subclass Not Emitting Event

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, events, coffeescript

**Short Version**: TCP Socket Subclass isn't retaining the Event Listeners.

I have a TCP custom socket (CoffeeScript):

```
jsonstream = require 'json-stream'
NetSocket = require('net').Socket
util = require 'util'

Socket = ->
  NetSocket.call(this);
  @actions = {}
  @setEncoding('utf8')
  @stream = jsonstream()
  @stream.on 'data', (data)=>
    console.log 'WTF WE GOT DATA', data
    @response(data)
  @pipe(@stream)
  return this

util.inherits(Socket, NetSocket);

Socket.prototype.response = (json)->
  console.log 'WTF IS THIS JSON', json
  id = json.id
  deferred = @actions[id]
  delete json.id
  return deferred.resolve(json) if deferred
  console.log 'wat', @listeners('task')
  console.log 'errors', @listeners('error')
  console.log 'errors', @listeners('data')
  res = @emit('task', json.execute)
  console.log res
```

The interface is rather simple. I send data, and when I receive data, I expect it to be JSON. I am streaming this socket into a `json-stream`, which handles the deserialization of JSON for me. Works great.

The problem is: **My socket is not retaining it's event listeners** for some reason.

Test Case (socket has been initialized to `s` and connected in a `before` block):

```
it 'should get a task to execute', (done)->
  @timeout(22000)

  console.log 'WTF', s.listeners('task')

  s.on 'task', (task)->
    console.log 'GOT TASK', task
    task.name.should.equal name
    done()

  s.on 'data', (data)->
    console.log 'DATA TEST', data

  s.on 'error', (err)->
    console.log 'ERROR', err

  console.log 'after'
  console.log 'TESTING', s.listeners('task')[0].toString()
```

Output from the test:

```
WTF []
before
SOMETHING ADDED task function (task) {
          console.log('GOT TASK', task);
          task.name.should.equal(name);
          return done();
        }
SOMETHING ADDED data function (data) {
          return console.log('DATA TEST', data);
        }
SOMETHING ADDED error function (err) {
          return console.log('ERROR', err);
        }
after
TESTING function (task) {
          console.log('GOT TASK', task);
          task.name.should.equal(name);
          return done();
        }
WTF WE GOT DATA { execute: 
   { __v: 0,
     name: 'd699ecbf-eda8-4588-a96f-b58e8a1c9a2e',
     time: '2015-03-06T02:25:40.577Z',
     _id: '54f91010bf41ed23cfe19339',
     created_at: '2015-03-06T02:25:20.579Z',
     updated_at: '2015-03-06T02:25:20.579Z',
     opts: { some: 'data' } } }
WTF IS THIS JSON { execute: 
   { __v: 0,
     name: 'd699ecbf-eda8-4588-a96f-b58e8a1c9a2e',
     time: '2015-03-06T02:25:40.577Z',
     _id: '54f91010bf41ed23cfe19339',
     created_at: '2015-03-06T02:25:20.579Z',
     updated_at: '2015-03-06T02:25:20.579Z',
     opts: { some: 'data' } } }
wat []
errors []
errors [ [Function: ondata] ]
false
```

From the logs, the Event Handler for `task` was added. After a set amount of time, data is received from the socket (*WTF WE GOT DATA*), the stream parses it into JSON, but when it calls `@emit`, **no listeners receive the event**. And indeed, at that point, looking at the listeners for `task` shows that no listeners are there.

Where'd my listeners go?

You can view all this code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ethanmick/future-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to leave the academic approach to people more interested, and forgo the custom socket approach. I switched to Socket.io instead, on both the server and client.

```
constructor: (@opts = {})->
@opts.port ?= DEFAULT_PORT
@opts.baseURL ?= "http://localhost:#{@opts.port}"
@socket = SocketIO("http://localhost:#{@opts.port}")
```

Is the resulting code. User's reference the `client.socket` and listen to events on that. Works great.